# Unit test for function returning Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, nock

Hi I have following function returning promise

```js
module.exports.getJwtToken = async() => {
    const httpSearchAddressUXConfig = {
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        mock: false,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      data: reqBody,
      method: 'POST',
      url: `${config.app.entTokens.host}`, // need to get from env variables
      timeout: config.app.enterpriseHTTPTimeout
    };
    try {
      const token = await axios(httpSearchAddressUXConfig);
      return token.data;
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
```

I have following test case which fails with unhandled Promise rejection error

```js
it('should find Jwt token ', async(done) => {

  const actualTokenfound = jwtTokenService.getJwtToken();
  return actualTokenfound
    .then(result => expect(result).toBe(Object))
    .then(done);

});
```

Any Suggestions ?

Comment: `.catch((err) => {
      throw err;
    });` is pointless, drop it. Also you should not make a function `async` if you don't use `await`.

Comment: Well, looks like your method (or the assertion) throws an exception, and you are never catching it anywhere (or calling `done`).

Comment: I have update the function block code. Still I'm getting same error

Comment: Oh, I actually was referring to the `it` callback, but right, `getJwtToken` has the same issue. And the `throw` inside the `catch` is still pointless. But no, those were only stylistic issues, fixing them won't change the behaviour.

Comment: read how to "throw" errors inside `async` functions
https://www.valentinog.com/blog/throw-errors-async-functions-javascript/

Comment: https://codepen.io/punith77/pen/WaQeqM?editors=0010
Actually my scenario is to test async function in catch block is it possible to do
Please suggest me better way to do

Answer (score 2):

If you define a async function, you don't need to use "done". I guess something like this it'll works.

```
it('should find Jwt token ', async () => {
  const actualTokenfound = await jwtTokenService.getJwtToken();
  expect(result).toBe(Object));
});
```